# Return the nth number

Tags: java

I am trying to return the nth number.Starting from 1 if a number is a multiple of 3 or 7 then that number is skipped and the next number is taken. However if the number is a multiple of both 3 and 7 then the number is not skipped.

```
public int Multiple(int num){
int n1 = n % 3;
int n2 = n % 7;
int count = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n1 != 0 || n2 != 0)
        count++;
    if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)
        count++;
    else if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0)
        continue;
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: You will learn more by trying to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
public static int nthNumber(int nth) {
    int num = 1;
    for (int count = 1; count < nth;) {
        if ((++num % 3 == 0) == (num % 7 == 0)) count++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

OUTPUT of the first 20 numbers:

```
 1 -> 1
 2 -> 2
 3 -> 4
 4 -> 5
 5 -> 8
 6 -> 10
 7 -> 11
 8 -> 13
 9 -> 16
10 -> 17
11 -> 19
12 -> 20
13 -> 21
14 -> 22
15 -> 23
16 -> 25
17 -> 26
18 -> 29
19 -> 31
20 -> 32
```

Comment: `!((num % 3 == 0) ^ (num % 7 == 0))` is kinda ugly. Just use this:
`((num % 3 == 0) == (num % 7 == 0))`

Comment: I improved the algorithm a bit further. Now it is even less complex.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put the following two lines inside the loop.

```
int n1 = n % 3;
int n2 = n % 7;
```

Also, your logic is a bit flawed. You should increment the counter exactly when `n1` and `n2` are both zero, or both nonzero.

```
int count = 0;
int i;
for (i = 1; count <= num; i++) {
    int n1 = i % 3;
    int n2 = i % 7;
    if (n1 != 0 && n2 != 0)
        count++;
    else if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0)
        count++;
    else // There is only one condition left. One is zero but the other is not.
        continue;
}

return i;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the nth number which satisfies your condition means , this code will be fine running.

```
public int Multiple(int n){

     int count=0;
     for(int i=1;;i++)
     {
         if(i%3==0&&i%7==0)
         {
             count++;
         }
         else if(i%3==0||i%7==0)
             continue;
         else
         {
             count++;
         }
         if(count==n)
         {
            return i;
         }

     }
```

}

Comment: what these numbers are from? ohh!!